# Service Worker with DOM

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is there any way to access another .js file and their functions form a Service Worker .js file? I want to show the notification count as the browser is open, on top of my website bell icon.

Comment: [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) do not act on the DOM, and indeed are not meant to work with the DOM. They are meant to sit between the app and the network, providing "proxy"-like services so that one can be disconnected, but still call services from the app.

Comment: I think you mean [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), but those still don't work directly on the DOM, since they are in a different thread. You'd use `postMessage` to send a message to the app, which would then affect the DOM.